# Time zone aware asp.net website for events: UTC vs local datetime

Tags: asp.net, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm working on an asp.net website that clients create events and users register for these events. After much reading on the subject of how to store and display datetime, I'm still confused about which route to take.

The most accepted solution (after searching on the subject) is store everything in UTC and substract clients's time zone offset for display. The alternative would be to store the datetime in event's time zone (local time of location of the event, not server) and display it as is to the client when requested. Wouldn't that be more efficient? Am I missing something? Do the daylight savings are taken into account that way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It'll be a lot easier in the long run to use UTC for all timestamps in your application and adjust based on user timezone

Answer (score 1):

Storing everything in UTC is the standard for a reason.

Your alternative of storing your events in local time will cause the confusion to users in different timezones to when the event actually took place.

Comment: You are absolutely right Jeff, but since an event belongs to a client and not all, why would that cause confusion? When displaying the starting time of the event, is it not logical to assume that the time displayed is the local time?

Comment: Datetimes are most often displayed in the same timezone as the client.  So for example, I am in EST, so all of the dates I usually see in forums etc.. are displayed to me in EST.

Comment: The easiest translation method is to capture a timestamp in UTC, then translate it to the client's timezone.  So in my example all the timestamps I see are UTC -5 hours.

Comment: I see your point but I think it's a different case here. For example a US citizen wants to attend an event in UK. I believe they should see the local time the event is taking place. Not theirs. Am I wrong?

Comment: In that scenario, I completely agree with you :)  BUT I would still store that event's time in UTC and display it in the timezone which it makes most sense.

Comment: Yes, to use utc as a reference point makes sense but then I have to convert all registration's datetimes on displaying. Is there a caveat if I use the event's local time zone as a reference point and get away with the conversions (may be thousands)?

Comment: The only issue I see is the assumption made by someone else looking at your data.  If you store it along with the Timezone or Location the event, I don't see a problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. Each event would have it's own time zone and upon saving a registration convert the datetime of registration to event's time zone (local time). In practice, I guess I have to store the offset from UTC for each event and then use that to calculate the local time for each registration.

Answer (score 1):

Using the event's location time zone as a reference point, we can do this to get the current local time (in .NET 3.5 or 4.0):

```
string EventTimeZoneId = "GTB Standard Time"; // for instance, this should be stored in DB as varchar[32]
DateTime EventLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, EventTimeZoneId);
```

This takes into account the daylight savings also. The only drawback I can think of, is that if the client picks the wrong time zone while creating an event, then all registrations will have a wrong time.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c# asp.net

1. To store in DB

> DateTime CurrntDate= DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now,
>   DateTimeKind.Unspecified); var _utc =
>   TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(CurrntDate,  TimeZoneInfo.Local);

1. Get date from db and convert as per client timezone and display.

It will put consistency in your Business Logic.

Comment: I see your point Sunil. Thanks. By the way the conversion function should be TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(CurrntDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local);